# lock canvas fail and canvas is null when useing SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

The question of Android SurfaceView.
I want to draw a Circle in SurfaceView ,but canvas is null in SimpleDraw method.Why?
No 1 ,canvas is null.
No 2,SimpleDraw method run in ClickListener,is right , canvas is not null,why?

```
1.public class SurfaceTestActivity extends Activity {
SurfaceView sfv;
SurfaceHolder sfh;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    sfv=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    sfh=sfv.getHolder();
    SimpleDraw();

}

void SimpleDraw(){
    Canvas canvas = sfh.lockCanvas(new Rect(0, 0, 300,
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 80, mPaint);
    sfh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
```

}

```
2.public class SurfaceTestActivity extends Activity {
Button simpleButton;
SurfaceView sfv;
SurfaceHolder sfh;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    simpleButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.simple);
    sfv=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    sfh=sfv.getHolder();
    simpleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //SimpleDraw();
        }
    });
}

void SimpleDraw(){
    Canvas canvas = sfh.lockCanvas(new Rect(0, 0, 300,
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 80, mPaint);
    sfh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
```

}

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question, can you clear up " No 2,SimpleDraw method run in ClickListener,is right , canvas is not null,why?" because the call to `SimpleDraw()` in the `onClick` method is commented out and won't run?

Comment: I'm Chinese,English isn't well.No 2 can run.what's different No 1 and No 2.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is timing.

No. 1  Tries to draw to the canvas before it is created and fails.  The call to `sfh.lockCanvas(...)` fails and returns `null`, not the `Canvas`.

No. 2  Tries to draw after the canvas has been created, so it works.

Do this:

```
public class SurfaceTestActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
SurfaceView sfv;
SurfaceHolder sfh;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    sfv=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    sfh=sfv.getHolder();
    sfh.addCallback(this);

}

void SimpleDraw(){
    Canvas canvas = sfh.lockCanvas(new Rect(0, 0, 300,
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()));
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 80, mPaint);
    sfh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}



@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // draw AFTER surface created!
    simpleDraw();

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
```

CHANGES:

adding `SurfaceHolder.Callback`

adding `sfh.addCallback(this);`

adding 3 `@Override` methods with new `SimpleDraw` -- after the canvas is created.

Comment: `surfaceCreated(...)` will be called, but this requires `sfh.addCallback(this);`